# MySQL error while "insert" command

Tags: mysql, insert, syntax-error

The following is the schema of my table (name->add_to_cart);

```
add_to_cart_id   int(10) PK
created_date     timestamp
ip_address       varchar(17)
customer_id      int(11)
session_id       varchar(1024)
brand_id           int(11)
product_id       int(11)
sales_event_id   int(11)
quantity         int(11)
referer          varchar(1024)
user_agent       varchar(1024)
```

But whenever I am trying to do execute the following query

```
INSERT INTO `add_to_cart` (add_to_cart_id,created_date,ip_address,customer_id,session_id,sku_id,product_id,sales_event_id,quantity,referer,user_agent) VALUES (1,2011-02-24 20:40:34,66.65.135.89,70154,qbk5r0rg9sl2ndiimquvnsab46,83791,308933,10105,2,https://www.onekingslane.com/product/10105/308933,Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML);
```

I get the following error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near
>   '20:40:34,66.65.135.89,70154,qbk5r0rg9sl2ndiimquvnsab46,83791,308933,10105,2,http'
>   at line 1 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'U' at line 1 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Intel Mac OS X
>   10_6_5' at line 1 ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'en-us) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML)'
>   at line 1

What am i doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to quote string values

```
INSERT INTO `add_to_cart`
(
    add_to_cart_id,
    created_date,
    ip_address,
    customer_id,
    session_id,
    sku_id,
    product_id,
    sales_event_id,
    quantity,
    referer,
    user_agent
)
VALUES
(
    1,
    '2011-02-24 20:40:34',
    '66.65.135.89',
    70154,
    'qbk5r0rg9sl2ndiimquvnsab46',
    83791,
    308933,
    10105,
    2,
    'https://www.onekingslane.com/product/10105/308933,Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_5; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML);'
)
```

Comment: What Joe said - strings go in single-quotes, numbers do not.  Escape your strings, don't escape your numbers.

Comment: Hey.. Yeah.. stackoverflow asks me to wait for sometime before i accept an answer.. :P

Comment: No worries, it does do that :P Cheers

Comment: the mistake is as common as missing a `;` (semi-colon) in C/C++/Java and other high-level languages